# ImportError: cannot import name 'Class_name2'

Tags: python, qt, python-import, importerror

As many others I'm stucked with the following issue : **ImportError**

I've checked for many solution and they are all related to pip and other way to install and uninstall packages/modules.

In my case, except PySide2 I'm only using my own modules and I simply can't import one of these because of this error. I don't see anything in particular that might cause this issue and after some hours searching for nothing I would need your help !

The beginning of the main package **main_window.py** looks like this :

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

from package_name1 import Class_name1

from package_name2 import Class_name2

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        super().__init__()
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.resize(1200, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle("APP NAME")
        self.setup_ui() 
        ...
```

The other package that cause problem here, the **package_name2.Class_Name2** looks like this :

```
from package_name1 import Class_name1

from main_window import MainWindow

class Class_name2(Class_name1, MainWindow):    

    def method_1(self):
        variable_1 = self.variable_1
        variable_2 = self.variable_2
        variable_3= self.variable_3
        ...
```

**Class_name2** herit from **Class_name1** and **MainWindow** because it needs variable and methods located in each.

Let me know in case you would need further details, thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Hi there, nobody experienced such case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens probably because a circular imports error:

You are importing MainWindow from main_window.py in package_name2.Class_Name2 and importing that Class_Name2 to main_window.py.

To avoid this you can simply create another file that handles all the import objects and export them to the other files